# help with /etc/network/interface

Tags: networking

I'm trying to set up my network using `/etc/network/interfaces`

When I restart network interface using `sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1`, the system changes the current IP as the file I show before. But the system keeps rotating the IP.

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo iface lo inet loopback

The primary network interface

auto eth1 iface eth1 inet static 
address 192.168.1.20 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.1 
brodcast 192.168.1.255 
nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change it to:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static 
address 192.168.1.20 
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 192.168.1.1 
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Is eth1, by chance, wireless? If so, you will need to declare an SSID and, hopefully, a WPA2 password.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1
```

The -v means verbose, you will have a chance to see what, if anything, went wrong and correct it.

I hope you meant /etc/network/**interfaces**.

If you are still having trouble, you may have a typographical error. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces  >  interfaces.txt
```

Find the file interfaces.txt in your user directory and paste it here so we may proofread it. http://paste.ubuntu.com/ Give us the link in your reply.

Comment: hi first of all thank four your help ! yes i mean /etc/network/interfaces im sorry for that mistake and its not a wifi . i do the change that you told me, and when i try to use the : sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1 the system respond me : etc/network/interfaces:9: interface lo declared allow-auto twice
ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces" again thank you

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: its done i so when i paste the config you give me i make a mistake really sorry for bother you ... , really appreciate the help !!

Comment: So, it's working as expected now? Awesome!

Comment: yes !!! it was a syntax error .... really appreciate !!

Comment: hi how you doing yesterday when i went to contact to my server i realice the server continue rotating the ip . so i start chacking if the networking service was running right and i realice a dhcp deamon so i killed and it seems like now its working ,and the sistem quit rotating ip . thnx 4 the help and sorry for disturbing again with such little issue .

Comment: So now it's working perfectly or do you need help?

Comment: i think its ok . i just add that to complete what left on the  steps ...